# jQuery - Get offset of a single letter in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some spans that auto generate and I need to find a way for jQuery to get the position of a specific letter.

For example:
If the span is: `<span>300 x 9</span>`
And the second span is : `<span>400 x 30</span>`

If I had a formula to figure out which position the zero is in, how would I get the offset of that digit in the span? So for the first span how would I get an offset for the zero at the end of 300, and for the second span how would I target the offset of the 0 in 30?

Basically I'm lacking some logic to fill in the blank of how to target an individual letter in jQuery? Is that possible without breaking the span in to more elements?

**EDIT: This will be used for animation purposes, basically to have an element appear over the zero and then move to a different position.. I just need the starting position for the animation in the end. Not sure if that's necessary information.**

Comment: Just to be clear : you want to retrieve the (x,y) coordinates in the page of a specific letter in a span tag ?

Comment: This is possible, but it will *not* be trivial. Can you post your current animation code so we can use it as a starting point?

Comment: how bout this? http://jsfiddle.net/wzKfX/

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it's just going to be using GSAP with TweenMax.from(roundBall, 0.25, {left: storedOffsetLeft, top: storedOffsetTop})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get the offset of a letter without first wrapping it in it's own element. You can wrap each element in it's own element, no problem. Just map the values to values contained in individual elements, and join them up:

```
var parts = $.map($('span').text().split(""), function(v){
    return '<span>'+v+'</span>';   
}).join("")
$('span').html(parts);
```

You can then get the offset of any span that may be within. If, for instance, we wanted to get the offset of the second 0 found in our original string, we could do like so:

```
var cords = this.find('span').filter(":contains('0')").eq(1).offset();
```

When you have the offsets, you just need to place the original HTML string back in your parent `<span>`.

If you put all this together you could make yourself a nice little plugin:

```
$.fn.letterOffset = function(v,i){
    var orig = this.text(), parts = $.map(orig.split(""), function(v){
        return '<span>'+v+'</span>';   
    }).join("");
    this.html(parts);
    var cords = this.find('span').filter(":contains('"+v+"')").eq(i?i-1:0).offset();
    this.html(orig);
    return cords;
}
```

To return the left-offset of the second zero now, we would do:

```
var offsetOfSecondZero = $('span').letterOffset("0",2).left
```

I've used `<span>`s to wrap each letter here, but you can use any element you want. Remember that you want to use an `inline` element.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjJn6/)

Comment: What if the document's CSS includes styling on `span` elements? What about wrapping each letter in a custom element instead: `return '<letter>'+v+'</letter>';`

Comment: Well that's the sort of thing the OP would change. I can only go on the information provided. Using a `<span>` is just an example for this demonstration.

Comment: The OP specified they are animating a `span`, but your solution is using a totally separate `span` element to calculate the letter offset. I'm suggesting that you replace the `span` element in your solution's map with something that's not likely to conflict with existing styles. In any case, the approach you suggest is fine, I'm just pointing out a possible conflict case.

Comment: Awesome thank you both! I didn't know you can make an element a completely custom name like letter or any other name. That's extremely helpful because as Palpatim guessed I have very specific controls set on each span. Both really helped!